# iOS : How to make sure background music consistantly play & stop in all XIB by using only one press button?

Tags: objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer, background-music

I have an iPad app with one background music button. The background music is looping all in the main XIB & the 2nd XIB. Basically, I can on & off the music successfully. My problem now is when i press the 2nd viewController button, my background music is mess up. I can on & off the music but mess up with the previous main controller's background music. How do I avoid that? Any suggestion code for Xcode4?

Here is my sample code in the mainController. I copy this in the 2nd viewController, it will mess up the background music. Any great suggestion code?

```
 - (IBAction)toggleMusic {

        if ([self.player isPlaying] == YES) {
            [self.player stop]; 
        } else {
            [self.player play];
        }
        self.playBgMusic.enabled = YES;

    }
```

Comment: I truly do not understand why people tag questions with 'xcode4.2' that clearly have nothing to do with Xcode, but objective-c.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but why don't you create singleton object for managing sounds? You'll have the reference then. It seems more aprioprate as the background music belongs more to the application than to single view(you use it in each view). The code will look like this then:

```
 - (IBAction)toggleMusic {

    if ([[[BackgroundMusic sharedMusic] player] isPlaying] == YES) {
        [[[BackgroundMusic sharedMusic] player] stop]; 
    } else {
        [[[BackgroundMusic sharedMusic] player] play];
    }
    self.playBgMusic.enabled = YES;

}
```

Comment: How do I declare that BackgroundMusic? I am pretty new in referencing.

Comment: Here is my new solution.Hope you can help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455576/ios-how-to-reference-a-music-background-from-a-singleton-class)